# Can you update the database using a LINQ to SQL Entity?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Using LINQ to SQL in WCF I have a update record methods which ATM I manually assign each updated property.
Eg.

```
public void UpdateMachineRecord(Guid SessionID, int MachineRecordID, MachineRecord machineRecord)
{
    if (!ValidSession(SessionID))
        return;

    using (MMHLINQSQLDataContext database = new MMHLINQSQLDataContext())
    {
        MachineRecord record = database.MachineRecords.Single(mr => mr.Job.OperationID == MachineRecordID);
        record.ChangedBy = UserSession(SessionID).Name;
        record.ChangedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        record.Date = machineRecord.Date;
        record.EDI = machineRecord.EDI;
        ...
        database.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

My questions is: Is there a way to update the record using an entire entity?

Eg.

```
public void UpdateMachineRecord(Guid SessionID, int MachineRecordID, MachineRecord machineRecord)
{
    if (!ValidSession(SessionID))
        return;

    using (MMHLINQSQLDataContext database = new MMHLINQSQLDataContext())
    {
        MachineRecord record = database.MachineRecords.Single(mr => mr.Job.OperationID == MachineRecordID);
        record = machineRecord;
        database.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL, or LINQ to Entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this.

```
database.MachineRecords.Attach(machineRecord, true);
database.SubmitChanges();
```

This will attach it as a modified entity (that's what the boolean parameter is for)

Comment: Thanks :) Exactly what I was after